# Problem with defining parenthesis command in Texmaker

Tags: formatting, texmaker

I am new to LaTeX and have been trying to redefine the `\left(` command to become `\(`. for some reason TeXmaker won't let me do this, it keeps telling me that `\(` is already defined but then when I type `\(` in math mode it has a fit. What should I do?

Here is my preamble:

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article} 
 \setlength\parindent{0pt}

 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % input encoding UTF-8

 \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

 \usepackage{color}

 \usepackage[margin=3.0cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{float}
 \usepackage{array}
 \usepackage{url}
 %
 %
 \newcommand{\D}{\partial} %partial operator
```

Comment: I suggest you not to redefine `\left`. Use the Find/Replace technique.

Comment: You certainly do *not* want to redefine `\left(` by `\(`; the former can only occur in math mode, whereas the latter marks the start of inline math mode. Did you mean `(` instead?

Comment: I basically want to be able to get a `\left(` by typing something short. `\(` seemed like the natural choice. 

@Sigur good suggestion, thanks.

Comment: @user27182, `\( \)` is the same as `$ $`, it is the way to change from text mode to math mode.

Comment: @Sigur *Almost* the same `:)`

Comment: @user27182 Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite `LaTeX's` internal definitions easily enough. It really isn't a good idea, though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand\({\left(}
\renewcommand\){\right)}
\begin{document}
\[
\( \frac{a}{b} \)
\]
\end{document}
```

It would be better to use something like `\lp` and `\rp`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\lp{\left(}
\newcommand\rp{\right)}
\begin{document}
\[
\lp \frac{a}{b} \rp
\]
\end{document}
```